# Food Rhyme with No

Tags: word-choice, rhymes, food

So I've been looking into lots of different food to respond for a dance, and I was going to do something like using the food as trying to rhyme with "no" but it'll be a yes, don't get me wrong I'm not a jerk, she just had to find the yes in a pile of hay, because it's a cowboy themed dance.

I've looked and looked for a food, but to no avail.

I'd prefer junk food. Also the food MUST be packaged and preferably sweet, she has a sweet tooth, and doesn't like spicy things.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [Pho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pho) looks like an answer but actually isn't.

Comment: Hostess Ho Ho's?

Comment: @Oldcat that's a really great idea! Unfortunately I already responded :/

Comment: How about fish eggs -- roe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better go with cookie dough or Oreo.

Comment: So then you agree that Oreo is a rhyme?

Answer (score 1):

"[Cheerio](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cheerio)" is a junk food and rhymes with "no."

Consider "burrito" and "oleo" also.

Comment: I don't know if I'd consider cheerios as a junk food... But +1 for effort. Would Oreos be a near rhyme or would that be a good rhyme. Example: So I'll give you these Oreos, so your not empty handed when i say...

Comment: But "Oreos" doesn't rhyme with "no," does it?

Comment: That's what I'm not sure of. It ends with the "owe" sound as does no, but the extra 's' makes me wonder.

Comment: @ermanen Sure. But it doesn't rhyme with "no" in the plural.

Answer (score 1):

Taco, nacho, burrito

There is even a song already:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuEw6P5OBuw

---

What about "merlot"? (a type of wine)

What about "gelato"? (a type of ice cream)

There is "jell-o" and "cornetto" also.

---

Finally, you can check this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WmUE.jpg

Comment: +1 for effort, but i don't want to leave tacos, or burritos or any food likewise on her front porch. Preferably something packaged, sorry i wasn't specific enough

Comment: Also on the Merlot: we're in highschool, and she's LDS, so that's definitely a no go.